# Communicating with Slot from parent Component in Svelte

Tags: binding, components, svelte

I made a Wrapper Component with Edit Cancel and Update buttons and a slot for an input to be updated.

I'm looking for a clean way to enable the Update button in the Wrapper only when the internal Edit field has been changed and to save the value on Update click.

It's a bit hard to explain so I created a REPL

https://svelte.dev/repl/ad9dc5954f60487d9a9e01f81a1bccc7?version=3.38.2

Comment: What's the point of the slot if you know there will be an input? Why not just put the input inside the wrapper?

Comment: It won't be only an input, it could be a select, or an entire form